# Cakephp 3.0 form dropdown how to show level

Tags: forms, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to add a form field for gender below is my code :

$options = ['m' => 'Male', 'f' => 'Female'];
    echo $this->Form->select('gender', $options);

But in my view file I am unable to see lebel gender  is there any other code which can help me suggest .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From->select doesn't give a proper label. Just do:

```
echo $this->Form->input('gender', array(
    'options' => $options,
    'type' => 'select',
    'empty' => 'Select the gender',
    'label' => 'Gender'
   )
);
```

Comment: all the lebel for password and others are in dark color but in your code it is lighter is there any way to fix that

Comment: can you link the website or is it in local? you should change the CSS if you want to change the color

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?= $this->Form->select('gender', ['m' => 'Male', 'f' => 'Female'], ['class' => 'form-control', 'required' => true])?>
```